# C++ Program with connect to FTP directory

Tags: c++, ftp

I trying to create some program with connection to some FTP address.
I have only basic elements on this moment and now I stopped at FTP connection.
What should I do to connect to my FTP address ? 
Someone maybe have some template with code ?

Answer (score 0):

You may see the code here. It is just how to connect to the server, and it use the default port 21. It passes IP address as a char*.

```
#include &ltnetinet/in.h> 
#include &ltsys/socket.h>  
#include &ltnetinet/in.h> 
#include &ltarpa/inet.h>  
int CFTP::ftp_connect(const char* ip)  
{  
    m_sockctrl = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);  
    if(0==m_sockctrl)return -1;  
    struct sockaddr_in addr;  
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  
    addr.sin_port = htons(21);  
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);  
    int err = connect(m_sockctrl,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));  
    if(err)return -1;  
    err = ftp_checkresp('2');  
    if(err)return -1;  
    return 0;  
}
```